# BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending resetting

Tags: c#, datagridview, backgroundworker, userform

I have `DataGridView` in UserForm application, which I populate from SQL server with `BackgroundWorker` to keep user ability to check already loaded data.

My philosophy is:

1. Read data in main `Thread`, show data in `DataGridView`
2. Start `BackgroundWorker`, where I loop by `While` till new data are requested or indefinitly.

My trouble is, that data are populated in `DataGridView` only if it's called in main `Thread`, but not from `bw_ProgressChanged`.

It works if I am calling `While` loop in main `Thread`, so database reading is fine.

Methods for work with DB and DataGridView:

```
private void SendRequest(string sql)
        {
            sqlDataReader = new SqlCommand(sql, connection).ExecuteReader();
        }

private void GetResponse()
        {
            dt.Load(sqlDataReader, LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
            sqlDataReader.Close();
        }

private void UpdateTable()
        {
            dtAll.DataSource = dt; //dtAll DataTable binded to DataGridView
        }
```

`BackgroundWorker` Events:

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            { 
                SendRequest("select top 5 * from table_1 order by tag");
                GetResponse();
                bw.ReportProgress(i);
                i++;
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage);
            UpdateTable();
        }

private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: A fundamental bug is that you update `dt` from a worker thread while it is also being used as a data source.  ProgressChanged only does something useful on the first call, nothing but trouble will evolve after that.  Not limited to never being able to stop the worker and not being able to safely close the form.  Get ahead by never writing a worker thread like that, keep them short and snappy.

Comment: ProgressChanged event works fine while I'm writing to Console number of rows from 'dt'. And 'dt' itself has no troubles with updates while it's done in main thread. Just 'DataGridView.Refresh()' method has to be called.

Comment: Running code that is not thread-safe from a worker thread usually seems to "work fine".  Until it doesn't, never happens when you debug, it will be your user that gets to deal with it.  Finding out that it goes wrong so early makes you a lucky programmer.  You need more luck, you can't get it here.  All we have to provide is advice.